# log4j2 integration with play framework fails

Tags: java, playframework, log4j2

I have a java app using play framework(2.5.5) which I am trying to integrate with log4j2 library with no luck.

I get the following errors when I run it as:
sbt -Dlog4j.configurationFile=conf/log4j2.xml

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/shishir/repos/jio-money/jiomoney-wallet-backend/target/universal/stage/lib/ch.qos.logback.logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/shishir/repos/jio-money/jiomoney-wallet-backend/target/universal/stage/lib/org.apache.logging.log4j.log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

I have followed the setup guide and update my build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  disablePlugins(PlayLogback)
...

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-slf4j-impl" % "2.4.1" exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic"),
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.4.1"  exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-core"),   
"org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.4.1"
```

My log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="file" target="/tmp/app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/ level="DEBUG">
        <AppenderRef ref="file"/ level="TRACE">
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Please let me know if I am missing something, or how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

There are two SLF4J bindings in your classpath, you must exclude `logback-classic` binding from your classpath.

Comment: I understand, that why I added exclude("ch.qos.logback", "logback-classic") in the dependency list, and also disabled PlayLogBack from the root. Yet, I see the 2 SLF4J bindings

Comment: Log4j2 related artifacts don't have compile dependencies on logback, I guess something else artifacts are depending on those.

Comment: I got : log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. Seems it tries to file a properties file despite specifying at CLI to use the xml file

Answer (score 0):

Play uses Logback by default, but it is possible to configure Play to use another logging framework as long as there is an SLF4J adapter for it.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger#Using-a-Custom-Logging-Framework